# Entity inheritance in Doctrine doesn't include OneToOne-relationships

Tags: symfony, inheritance, doctrine-orm

Trying to utilize inheritance, I've created the following entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="persons")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Image", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="image_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $image;
}

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="actors")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Actor extends Person
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="character", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $character;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="images")
 * @ORM\Entity()
 */
class Image
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $path;
}
```

Which almost works perfectly. The generated `actors`-table contains all the `persons`-fields, except for the `image`-relation. I've tried to change the relation to a `ManyToOne`, which didn't help.

How to make the `Actor`-entity also inherit all joined fields? I'm open to other solutions, if the above isn't ideal.

Comment: You could try looking into **table inheritance** which is something that Doctrine supports. Take a look at [Class Table Inheritance](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance)

Comment: hey, did you find solution to this?

Comment: @TomekKobyliński: No, if I recall correctly I sadly had to duplicate the relation on both children.

Comment: yeah, finnally me too. thanks;)

Comment: The _Class Table Inheritance_ link in the comments is dead. The new link is https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/current/reference/inheritance-mapping.html#class-table-inheritance

Answer (score 0):

You need a parent construct in your Actor class:

```
public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        // your own logic
    }
```

It is advised that you add an ID aswell.

Comment: Calling the parent constructor sadly didn't help. Nor did explicitly declaring an id in the `Actor` class..